# Setup application

Tags: wpf, installation

Is there any alternative way to create setup for my WPF application?

The build in setup creator of MS has same issues with Install/UnInstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is WiX toolset http://wix.codeplex.com/ as well as InstallShield http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm